# Execute .bat script as administrator from gpedit.msc

Tags: windows-10, command-line, batch, batch-file, group-policy

In `gpedit.msc` under Computer config -> Windows settings -> Scripts -> Shutdown I added my .bat file to execute it each time when shutting down the PC, but I would get error `access denied`. It's a `taskkill` command to kill certain task. It gives same error if you execute it with mouse left-click, but works if you execute it inside cmd prompt opened as administrator.

How do I execute this under administrator privileges?

Script: `taskkill /f /im googledrivesync.exe` I'm working on this workaround, it's a known bug for Google Drive not quitting on system shut down.

Comment: Use Task scheduler. You can then make it run with highest privileges, or use NTAUTHORITY\SYSTEM as user

Comment: @LPChip There is no event on task scheduler as Shut down or system log off or any similar I can't find.

Comment: In your `.bat` script, use something like `SCHTASKS /RUN /TN "KillGoogledrivesync"` where `KillGoogledrivesync` is a task to run `taskkill /f /im googledrivesync.exe` in _task scheduler_. Should be defined to run as user `SYSTEM` with the highest privileges. Enable running on demand, do not trigger on any event or time.